# Is there a classical way for securing a SPA and an API using Google Cloud App Engine?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, single-page-application

I’d like to use the Google Cloud App Engine to serve a SPA and a REST API, both secured behind an authentication wall.

Is there any recommended way of doing this?

So far, I’ve found tutorials on how to secure an API, but not an SPA. Both ends are served from different projects, but I’d like to have a unique authentication step.

Typical flow would be:

1. Before serving the SPA source code, ask for authentication
2. Once authenticated, serve the SPA and allow the SPA to access the API resources

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So far I’ve reviewed the documentation, it doesn't seem like there is any specific recommended way to authenticate an SPA within Google Cloud.

However, I think a pretty secure way would be to authenticate your application using the [Toolkit Identity API](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/) of Google. The procedure would be to call this API from App Engine as the first necessary requirement.

This method works with [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#identitytoolkitv3) [access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#obtainingaccesstokens). I think you could request for authentication credentials to your users before launching your application and granting access to the other resources/APIs.